# mysql database not updating when I access Java servlet from android

Tags: java, android, mysql, email, servlets

I have been creating an android app. I designed a signup form . Here when people click the signup button the details are added to the mysql table(contains confirmation code as a field.) and the confirmation code is initially set to NULL and then a servlet is called . This servlet contains the code that generates a 4 digit random number and adds it to the mysql table for the particular entry. Then the servlet calls a method in another class that sends confirmation email to the user with the code.

Now when I run the app and servlet a confirmation code is generated and it is sent to the user vie email. But the problem is the mysql table is not getting updated. Note: The code for updation of mysql table is given above the code that send email. However the same servlet updates the mysql table and sends email on submission of a HTML form.

Don't know how to solve this..
For info I am hosting the application on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

This is the Servlet part:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest      request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    System.out.println("fdsfsdf");
    mBean = new MailSenderBean();
        Random n=new Random();
        int no=n.nextInt();
        no%=10000;
        if(no<0)
        {
            no=-no;
        }
        String code="0000"+no , name = request.getParameter("name"), email = request.getParameter("email");
        code=code.substring(code.length()-4, code.length());
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(AppConfig.dbUrl,AppConfig.dbUname, AppConfig.dbPwd);
            PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("update signup_users set code=\'"+code+"\' where name=\'"+name+"\'");
            pst.execute();
            mBean.sendMail(name, email, code);
            System.out.println("name="+name+",email="+email+",code="+code);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(""+e);
        }
    }
```

and my client side code in android app is

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient  = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(AppConfig.serverUrl);
    List lst =new ArrayList();
    lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(lst));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your code... otherwise we're all just guessing.

Comment: please check this .. I have added the servlet code here.

Comment: Please, post the client code as well. Since you said that your code works well when a http request is made using a html form,  the problem may be on the client side (i.e. the Android app) Anyway, did you check your app server logs?

Comment: Well, you certainly have some other issues here... for starters, you are not using `PreparedStatement` correctly. You should be paramatizing your inputs to it, with `?` characters...http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Comment: I have added the client side code also.. Check that too..

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from a friend. I was using the wrong field to update in android app but I used the appropriate key in html form. That is why I got wrong output from android app alone..!!